# Swift: how to force UIabel to occupy remaining free space

Tags: swift, uilabel, interface-builder

I have a UIView containing:

- UIButton: (contentMode = Aspect Fit)
- UILabel:(numberOfLines = 0, lineBreakMode = byWordWrapping, contentMode = Aspect Fill)
- UISwitch: ()

I would like the width and number of lines of the UILabel  to adapt to the content of the localized text of UIButton and UILabel.

How should I proceed ?

Behavior expected:

```
____________________________________________________________________
|          |                                            |          |
| UIButton |                 UILabel                    | UISwitch |
|          |                     |                      |          |
_________________________________v__________________________________
```

Fred

Comment: What you are looking for is called `UIStackView` (horizontal)

Comment: I started first with a UIStackView but my UISwitch was out of the screen !!! Although My stack had right leading, trailing, top and botton constraint :-(

Comment: Constraints are not a problem, you have to setup compression resistance and hugging prirorities.

Comment: Thank @Sulthan, that was my missing point

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give it the required constraints in order to make it fit as you like. You need to provide more details, in order for me to tell you about the constraints you would want. With current information assuming that your button and switch have fixed widths, and are pinned at leading and trailing of superview end respectively. then go through a check of following constraints

(1) give leading constraint of your label equal to trailing constraint of button
(2) give trailing constraint of your label equal to leading constraint of switch
(3) give top and bottom constraint of your button equal to top and bottom constraint of label
(4) give top and bottom constraint of your switch equal to top and bottom constraint of label

Finally, provide a constraint for the y position of your label, and you are good to go.

Another potential solution is using a horizontal stack view, which will save a lot of these constraints.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I tried... but the size of my button is not as small as possible (I expext it to fit the text)

So, I have added these constraints

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
 resetButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.leadingAnchor),
 resetButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rawLabel.leadingAnchor),
 rawLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: directSwitch.leadingAnchor),
 directSwitch.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.trailingAnchor),
 resetButton.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: bottomView.topAnchor),
 rawLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.topAnchor),
 directSwitch.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: bottomView.topAnchor),
 resetButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: bottomView.bottomAnchor),
 rawLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.bottomAnchor),
 directSwitch.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: bottomView.bottomAnchor),
 resetButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.centerYAnchor),
 rawLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.centerYAnchor),
 directSwitch.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.centerYAnchor)
])
```

and this viewWillAppear func

`override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    resetButton.sizeToFit()
    rawLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    rawLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    rawLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = bottomView.frame.width - resetButton.frame.width - directSwitch.frame.width
}`

Comment: I solve my issue adding a higher hugging priority to my UIButton (thanks to @Sulthan)